# asp.net using html control to pass value to code behind c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a drop down control in html which is basically a href disguised as dropdown populated with "<'li>" elements.I want to pass parameter like username from this link to next page .How can I achieve this?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="account.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="personalize.aspx">Personalize</a></li>
      <li><a href="tools.aspx">My Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="appointments.aspx">Appointments</a></li>
      <li class="label-danger"><a href="logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

basically what I want is that in personalize.aspx I want something like a href="personalize.aspx?Name=+textbox1.text" or some session variable, How can I achieve this
This code is located in "reguser.aspx" to which the "login.aspx" sends a session variable which has username. How can I carry forward that value to "
"personalize.aspx"?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself
just posting here for someone looking for solution added this code in my "reguser.aspx"

```
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="account.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             <%string Name = Request.QueryString["Name"];%>
                            <li><a href="personalize.aspx?Name=<% Response.Write(Name);%>">Personalize</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tools.aspx">My Tools</a></li>
                            <li><a href="appointments.aspx">Appointments</a></li>
                           <li class="label-danger"><a href="logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```